# Microsoft Teams does not display properly URL preview trough Graph API

Tags: url, share, preview, microsoft-teams

I tried a lot of different ways but I don't achieve the expected result. There is nothing in the web related with what I am trying to do and I decided to ask for assistance here. Here is the case:

Requirement: Display URL preview in Microsoft Teams channel. Eventually enable content collaboration for external file. File will be served with access token. File preview should be available as it is when the link is sent manually in the chat.

Expected result: [image: url preview microsoft teams]

Actual result: [image: escaped url preview]
as you can see, the url has been escaped and shown as pure text

I use .net core and Microsoft.Graph 1.15.00

As the message content type is HTML I tried showing it in iframe, also tried sharepoint embed link also with iframe and - nothing works. Then tried referenceAttachment as described in Graph API docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/referenceattachment?view=graph-rest-beta but it's not working again.

This is a piece of my code where I construct adaptive card and send it to teams - this functionality works perfectly. I am also sending a pure text message with the card as you can see in the code. The issue comes only with the URL.. This is a snapshot of the final version. The added part is highlighted in red. When I am adding this ReferenceAttachment. I get Error from the Graph API
[image]

[image]

Does anyone knows how can I achieve the desired result with MS Teams?

Thanks in advance:)

Comment: Graph API does not support sending a link with preview.

Comment: You can write messageHandler in your app manifest. Please take a look at [Add Rich preview messages using link unfurling](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-teams/blogs/add-rich-previews-to-messages-using-link-unfurling/)

Comment: @Trinetra-MSFT yes - I saw that but this is for Bot app. That's a share on behalf of user. I was playing yesterday whole day with it and saw MS Teams is using internal API's. Graph API has referenceAttachment and thumbnail which are not working and I decided to construct an adaptive card by my own and show the file and the preview. I tried beta as well and it's not working well. :(

Comment: Could you please share you app manifest?

Comment: @Trinetra-MSFT there's no app manifest for this app. This app uses AAD and Graph API to share content on behalf of the users. It is not a bot app

Comment: It is ok. We've created it as adaptive card and looks ok :)